# Merge 2 csv files on multiple columns using python

Tags: python, csv, merge, duplicates

I have 2 `CSV` files contain thousands of data. Suppose the data from the files:

`first.csv`:

```
filename | type | size
----------------------
A        | doc  |   8
A        | doc  |  10
B        | pdf  |   5
```

`second.csv`:

```
filename | type | size
----------------------
A        | doc  |   8
A        | doc  |  10
C        | jpg  |   3
```

I need to merge both files based on multiple columns, namely `filename` and `type`. Add two new columns in the merged table from column `size` in both files.  Save it into new `csv` file. So the new table should be:

```
filename | type | size-1 | size-2
---------------------------------
A        | doc  |   8    |    8
A        | doc  |  10    |   10
B        | pdf  |   5    |    0
C        | jpg  |   0    |    3
```

I have written the code:

```
ds1 = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
ds2 = pd.read_csv('second.csv')

data_merge = ds1.merge(ds2, on=['filename','type'],how='outer',suffixes=('-1','-2'))
data_merge.fillna(0, inplace=True)
data_merge = data_merge.reset_index(drop=True)
data_merge.to_csv('new.csv')
```

When I execute the code, I got the new table with data `A` repeated many times by combining each value in column `size`.

```
filename | type | size-1 | size-2
---------------------------------
A        | doc  |   8    |    8
A        | doc  |   8    |   10
A        | doc  |  10    |    8
A        | doc  |  10    |   10
B        | pdf  |   5    |    0
C        | jpg  |   0    |    3
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: filename + type are not unique in either csv, perhaps you need to use row number as the key (I am uncertain if pandas has a builtin feature that does that or if you need to add a column for that)

Comment: @RoyShahaf I think you're right. I added one unique column in both files, and it works. Thanks